# Android ViewModel inside Service (Alternative)

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a service which provides UI that is visible to user most of the time.

I was experimenting with new Application Architecture when I came with a problem.

`MyModelviewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyModelviewModel.class);`

But as you know `this` can be only `AppCompat` or `Fragment`

Is there some alternative? or can I put observer directly on my `LiveData` like Im puting on `ViewModel`

```
viewModel.getList().observe(Playground.this, new Observer<List<TestEntity>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<TestEntity> items) {
        recyclerViewAdapter.addItems(items);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`LiveData` can be use independently without `ViewModel`,you can use `observeForever(Observer<T> observer)`, or `observe(LifecycleOwner owner, Observer<T> observer)` while you provide a proper `LifecycleOwner` instance, you can implement `LifecycleOwner` in your service or view.

`ViewModelProviders` just provides a cache of `ViewModel` for each `Fragment` or `Activity`, you can create your `ViewModel` directly by `new MyModelviewModel()`.

Comment: In case of creating new `ViewModel`, it will be destroyed with my activity rotation am I right? or how I am supposed to get same instance other way

Comment: If you want to create `ViewModel` in activity, use `ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(MyModelviewModel.class);`, it will get same instance after activity rotation. If you want to create `ViewModel` in service, just new it, I think we don't need to cache the viewmodel in service.

Comment: @AvatarQing Got it. But suppose if I use a ViewModel with just the constructor (without the ViewModelProviders) then would coroutine scope: [ViewModelScope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) will work properly?

Comment: @SahilSharma You should invoke viewmodel's clear() method manually to make viewModelScope work properly. You can review viewModelScope's source code to verify.

Answer (score 4):

Initialize with

```
new ViewModel()
```

in

```
onStartCommand
```