# How to inject ViewModel in service using hilt dagger

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I want to inject View Model in Service , how can it possible.

I recently started using DI in my project through Dagger Hilt. I'm having no problems when injecting viewModel instances into Activity/Fragment. But I am not sure how to inject this in service

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716548/android-viewmodel-inside-service-alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyService : Service(), ViewModelStoreOwner{
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    private val viewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)[MainViewModel::class.java]
    }
    private val store = ViewModelStore()
    override val viewModelStore get() = store
}

@Module
@InstallIn(ServiceComponent::class)
object ServiceModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideMainViewModelFactory(repository: MyRepository)= viewModelFactory {
        initializer { MainViewModel(repository) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).